# Grouping items in Python Dictionary by common value

Tags: python, dictionary, grouping

I have a nested dictonary that I'm iterating over, I'd like to make a new dictonary derived from the old dictonry that groups certain values together based on a value present in the old dictonary. To illustrate:

```
{'name': Fido, 'breed': Dalmatian, 'age': 3}
{'name': Rex, 'breed': Dalmatian, 'age': 2}
{'name': Max, 'breed': Dalmatian, 'age': 0}
{'name': Rocky, 'breed': Pitbull, 'age': 6}
{'name': Buster, 'breed': Pitbull, 'age': 7}
```

Would give me:

```
Dalmation: {'name': [Fido, Rex, Max], 'age': [3, 2, 0]}
Pitbull : {'name': [Rocky, Buster], 'age': [6, 7]}
```

I've tried to find an elegant and pythonic solution to this to no avail.

Comment: So what have you tried? Can you give us your code?

Comment: How is the input data a nested dictionary? Also why not show us your unelegant/unpythonic solution so that we may suggest improvements and also know that you have at least made some effort to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possibilities:

Example #1: http://ideone.com/RRzWaL

```
dogs = [
    {'name': 'Fido', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 3},
    {'name': 'Rex', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 2},
    {'name': 'Max', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 0},
    {'name': 'Rocky', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 6},
    {'name': 'Buster', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 7},
]

# get rid of duplicates
breeds = set([ dog['breed'] for dog in dogs ])

breed_dict = {}
for breed in breeds:
    # get the names of all dogs corresponding to `breed`
    names = [ dog['name'] for dog in dogs if dog['breed'] == breed ]

    # get the ages of all dogs corresponding to `breed`
    ages = [ dog['age'] for dog in dogs if dog['breed'] == breed ]

    # add to the new dict
    breed_dict[breed] = { 'age': ages, 'name': names }
```

I'll also add a simplification of @JohnGordon's code using `collections`'s `defaultdict`:

Example #2: http://ideone.com/B2xLGR

```
from collections import defaultdict

doglist = [
    {'name': 'Fido', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 3},
    {'name': 'Rex', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 2},
    {'name': 'Max', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 0},
    {'name': 'Rocky', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 6},
    {'name': 'Buster', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 7},
]
dogdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for dog in doglist:
    # `defaultdict` allows us to not have to check whether
    # a key is already in the `dict`, it'll just set it to
    # a default (`[]` in the inner dict in our case) 
    # if it's not there, and then append it.
    dogdict[dog['breed']]['name'].append(dog['name'])
    dogdict[dog['breed']]['age'].append(dog['age'])
```

Note that the second example using `defaultdict` will be faster than the first example, which has two separate list comprehensions (i.e., two separate inner loops).

Answer (score 2):

```
doglist = [
    {'name': 'Fido', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 3},
    {'name': 'Rex', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 2},
    {'name': 'Max', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 0},
    {'name': 'Rocky', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 6},
    {'name': 'Buster', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 7},
]
dogdict = {}

for dog in doglist:
    if dog['breed'] in dogdict:
        dogdict[dog['breed']]['name'].append(dog['name'])
        dogdict[dog['breed']]['age'].append(dog['age'])
    else:
        dogdict[dog['breed']] = {'name': [dog['name']], 'age': [dog['age']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` to segregate the dictionaries then construct the new dictionaries.

```
import itertools, collections, operator
dees = [{'name': 'Fido', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 3},
        {'name': 'Rex', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 2},
        {'name': 'Max', 'breed': 'Dalmatian', 'age': 0},
        {'name': 'Rocky', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 6},
        {'name': 'Buster', 'breed': 'Pitbull', 'age': 7}]

breed = operator.itemgetter('breed')
filtr = ['name', 'age']
new_dees = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(dees, breed):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for thing in group:
        for k, v in thing.items():
            if k in filtr:
                d[k].append(v)
    new_dees.append({key:d})
```

---

As an alternative you can just extract the values you want instead of using `if k in filtr`.  I haven't decided which alternate I like best so I'll post this also.

```
# using previously defined functions and variables
items_of_interest = operator.itemgetter(*filtr)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(dees, breed):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for thing in group:
        values = items_of_interest(thing)
        for k, v in zip(filtr, values):
            d[k].append(v)
    new_dees.append({key:d})
```